# Filtering a stream from another stream in one Flink execution

Tags: filter, stream, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm trying to detect patterns over an original input stream, and drop the first event of each match from the original input stream to create a modified stream. Then, detect other patterns on the modified stream.
The problem here is when I find the matches of patterns, how can I drop the resulting stream from the original input stream?
e.g., see code below:

```
List<DataEvent> events = readDataSet(filePath,"data.csv");
DataStream<DataEvent> eventStream = env.fromCollection(events);
PatternStream<DataEvent> publicPatternStream = CEP.pattern(eventStream, randomPatterns.get(num)).inProcessingTime();

DataStream<DataEvent> results = publicPatternStream.process(new PatternProcessFunction<DataEvent, DataEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void processMatch(Map<String, List<DataEvent>> map, Context context, Collector<DataEvent> collector) throws Exception {

                    collector.collect(map.get("start").get(0));
                }
            });
```

Now, the question is "how can I remove the events of *results* data stream from *eventStream*?"
One option is to write them in the file, but this way I need to run another job for the next patterns. I wonder if I can put the events of results data stream into a list and then update the initial event list.
I appreciate any help.

Comment: You can apply another pattern to the `results` stream emitted by the first pattern, and so on.

Comment: Dear David, let me explain it more. I have stream " 1, 2, 3, 4, 5" and the result of processing a pattern is "2, 5". Now, I want to create stream "1, 3, 4" which is the subtraction of result from primary stream. How can I do that? considering the indifinity of data streams in FlinkCEP.